# jQuery Change Default Table Header Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table styled with `boostrap` by default:

[image: table on click]

What I want to do is remove the grey from every other heading at the top, so all the headings have a white background. When a user clicks on a heading, its background color will change to a dark grey(like how 'marketplace' above is selected). my current jQuery will remove the original background color on page refresh(as seen below), but on click of any headers, it will add the default background color back(As seen above)  . I can obviously get the selection color change to work, but its not overriding my styling.

[image: table pre refresh]

I have a fiddle below but its not styling appropriately so i have attached the screen shots as well just for all the code to show.

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    var plan;
    $('.nested tr').hide();
    $('.nested tr#essential').show();



    $('.view').click(function() {
            console.log($(this).text());
            $(this).removeAttr('style').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
            plan = $(this).attr("id");
            $('.nested tr').hide();
            $('.nested tr#'+plan).show();       
        });
    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uaorqkx7/1/

Comment: Why not find the classes used for each of the headings and then override the css with your own?

Comment: @AnandG  it's in the Fiddle

Comment: @jeff i tried to set the color of those header elements to 'background: none 'but it was reverting on click of other headers

Comment: background:none is not doing what you expect/want it to (none is not a valid colour property). The docs will hopefully help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

please check this,

```js
var plan;
$('.nested tr').hide();
$('.nested tr#ess').show();

$('.view').click(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('style').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
  plan = $(this).attr("id");
  $('.nested tr').hide();
  $('.nested tr#' + plan).show();
});
```

```css
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

td{
  width:20%;
  height:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.normal_ td{
  width:20%;
  height:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.accordion td.selected {
  background-color: #333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="toptable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="accordion">
      <td id="ess" class="view">Ess</td>
      <td style="background: none" id="std" class="view">Std</td>
      <td id="pp" class="view">PP</td>
      <td style="background: none" id="mp" class="view">MP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normal_">
      <td colspan="4">
        <table class="nested" border="1">
          <tbody>

            <tr id="ess">
              <td>Built Tools</td>
              <td>✔</td>
              <td>Unlimited Postings</td>
              <td>✔</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="std">
              <td>Built Tools</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>Unlimited Postings</td>
              <td>✔</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="pp">
              <td>Built Tools</td>
              <td>✔</td>
              <td>Unlimited Postings</td>
              <td>-</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="mp">
              <td>Built Tools</td>
              <td>-</td>
              <td>Unlimited Postings</td>
              <td>-</td>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this doesnt remove the grey default color for header or make the selected header dark grey

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your fiddle code a little bit and i was able to change background color to red. Let me know if you don't get it.

[Check working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/uaorqkx7/45/)

```js
var plan;
$('.nested tr').hide();
$('.nested tr#ess').show();



$("tr.accordion td").on('click',function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
  $(this).removeAttr('style').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
  plan = $(this).attr("id");
  $('.nested tr').hide();
  $('.nested tr#' + plan).show();
  $(".view").removeAttr("style")
  
  $(this).attr("style","background-color:red !important;");
});
```